# how to call oracle package in reporting services

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I create reports using Microsoft reporting services with Oracle database. All stored procedures are contained in the package. I can't deal with the package. If you have any advice, I will be happy and thank you.

Comment: Please, give use more information. Question is not clear.

Comment: If you call a member procedure of a pl/sql package, it needs to look like this: `begin packageName.procedureName; end;` This works for example in an integration services package. If you do this in the sqlplus console, you need to finish with a new line and a `/`. Maybe this helps.

Comment: what I do is designing reports by using reporting services but my problem is the project database designed in oracle and all stored procedures are contained in oracle packages.when I try make a data set form database. I can't get stored procedure from package.

Comment: When you say "I can't get stored procedure from package", what does it really mean? Do you get some sort of an error? Does your computer crash? Is that forbidden by law in your location?

Comment: when I say "I can't get stored procedure from package" I mean "In adding new data set, I can choose between text, table and stored procedure by logic but when write the name of the stored procedure, it didn't appear"